# Avoid having Ctrl-X insert first item

Tags: vim

When I use Ctrl-X, the first item on the list is automatically inserted as a word. This is very annoying as I have to use C-N/C-P or remove characters if this wasn't the result I was after.

Is there a way to avoid having C-X insert the best match automatically so I can refine my search quicker?

An example:

```
a<C-x><C-p>
```

lists:

```
algorithm
... many, many more ...
axiom
```

I would like to then just press `x`, and `axiom` would be the only item in the list.
Now it completes to `algorithm` right away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want

```
:set completeopt+=longest
```

This only inserts the longest common text of the matches, not the full first match.

Additionally, you can make the first menu item pre-selected (but not yet inserted), so that a quick `<C-y>` (or even plain `<Enter>`) selects and inserts it. This is all described in [Make Vim completion popup menu work just like in an IDE](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Make_Vim_completion_popup_menu_work_just_like_in_an_IDE).

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I've spent way too little time in the wiki :(